# In android, Add 3 different fragments on single screen in landscape view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have to add three fragments in single screen in landscape mode. Please help me out how it can be achieved using fragment manager. attached is the dummy screen for the same.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your going to want to define a layout that includes 3 `FrameLayouts` that are all next to each other. Perhaps something like the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, from your parent `Fragment's` `onCreateView` method, inflate the layout resource that contains the above. At that point, use the `FragmentManager` to add each `Fragment` to the appropriate `FrameLayout` like so:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout_file, parent, false);

    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();

    fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_1, fragment1, "fragment_1")
            .commit();

    fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_2, fragment2, "fragment_2")
            .commit();

    fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_3, fragment3, "fragment_3")
            .commit();

    return v;
}
```

That, in a nutshell, should get your `Fragment's` displaying as you'd like. If you're using an `Activity` as the parent of this 3-`Fragment` layout, you can do pretty much the same thing from `onCreate`, just call `getFragmentManager()` rather than `getChildFragmentManager()`.